# pgsql Materialized view refresh

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, materialized-views

I use materialized view in pgsql and i wonder if there is a way to refresh a materialized view for example A after that another materialized view B has been completely refreshed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not refreshing then sequentially in one script?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HOW TO REFRESH MATVIEW**

**1. Bash Script**

**2. Create Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mv() RETURNS VARCHAR AS $LABEL$
DECLARE 
v_result integer;
BEGIN

refresh materialized view mv_b with data;

refresh materialized view mv_a with data;


RETURN ('Success');

END;
$LABEL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

## Execute select * from refresh_mv();

Comment: Hope this help you for your further development. GL :)

Comment: @poyofever. your welcome, glad if this ans help u :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query to refresh the view:

```
EXEC DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('EMP_MV');
SELECT 
    owner, mview_name, last_refresh_date 
FROM 
    all_mview;
```